# Modx Front End not Showing Up

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I installed modx Revolution and everything is working fine in the manager, except the front end, when i browse to the local website nothing shows up, just a

```
<html>
<head>
<title>MODX Revolution - Home</title>
 <base href="http://evosoccer.loc/EvoSoccer/" />
 </head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I checked the error log in/cache/logs and the log page from the manager and it has zero records, how do i troubleshoot this?

--
Regards.
Yehia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have no template or content installed...   by default a modx installation is completely empty.

you can install a demo site from the package management if you just wanted to kick the tires.... otherwise in the resource manager just place some content in the home template.  then you should see something.

-sean